# How to add category-slugs to a product URL in Shopware 6?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

By default, the Shopware 6 URLs for products are set like this:

`{{ product.translated.name }}/{{ product.productNumber}}` 
*=> /Product-Name/Number123*

Category URLs look like this:

`{% for part in category.seoBreadcrumb%}{{ part|lower  }}/{% endfor %}` 
*=> /parent-category/child-category*

I would like to add the product's main category's path to the product URL like it was possible in SW5 with `{sCategoryPath articleID=$sArticle.id}/{$sArticle.name}` 
*=> /parent-category/child-category/product-name*

Is there a way to achieve this in SW6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this out-of-the-box. Tested in Shopware 6.4.15.0:

```
{% for part in product.mainCategory.breadcrumb|slice(1)%}{{ part }}/{% endfor %}{{ product.translated.name }}/{{ product.productNumber }}
```

Will result in:

[image]

Category structure:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfectly. Do you - by any chance - also have an idea on how to achieve something like `{% if product.hasVariants and not product.isMainVariant %}?n={{ product.productNumber }}{% endif %}` - So "If the product has variations and it is not the main product, add the product-number as Query-Parameter"?

Comment: If you have multiple sales channels and set different main categories for each one, this will arbitrarily give you the same breadcrumb, whichever is fetched first, for the SEO url of **all** sales channels. Viable though if you only have a single sales channel.

Comment: @dneustadt is there a possibility similar to this, when i have multiple sales channel and set different main categories?

i thought something like this should work, but it does not, unfortunately:

{% for part in product.categories.sortByPosition().first.breadcrumb %}{{ part }}/{% endfor %}{{ product.translated.name|lower }}/{{ product.productNumber }}

i took that part from the documentation https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/settings/seo#product-detail-page

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write a plugin to achieve this. With your plugin you can then decorate `ProductPageSeoUrlRoute`.

```xml
<service id="Foo\MyPlugin\ProductPageSeoUrlRouteDecorator" decorates="Shopware\Storefront\Framework\Seo\SeoUrlRoute\ProductPageSeoUrlRoute">
    <argument type="service" id="Foo\MyPlugin\ProductPageSeoUrlRouteDecorator.inner"/>
    <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\Content\Category\Service\CategoryBreadcrumbBuilder"/>

    <tag name="shopware.seo_url.route"/>
</service>
```

In your decorator you then enhance the criteria to fetch the main categories, use the injected `CategoryBreadcrumbBuilder` to generate the breadcrumb and enrich the data for the route generation with the breadcrumb array.

```php
class ProductPageSeoUrlRouteDecorator implements SeoUrlRouteInterface
{
    private SeoUrlRouteInterface $decorated;

    private CategoryBreadcrumbBuilder $breadcrumbBuilder;

    public function __construct(SeoUrlRouteInterface $decorated, CategoryBreadcrumbBuilder $breadcrumbBuilder)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
        $this->breadcrumbBuilder = $breadcrumbBuilder;
    }

    public function getConfig(): SeoUrlRouteConfig
    {
        return $this->decorated->getConfig();
    }

    /**
     * @internal (flag:FEATURE_NEXT_13410) make $salesChannel parameter required
     */
    public function prepareCriteria(Criteria $criteria/*, SalesChannelEntity $salesChannel */): void
    {
        /** @var SalesChannelEntity|null $salesChannel */
        $salesChannel = \func_num_args() === 2 ? func_get_arg(1) : null;

        $this->decorated->prepareCriteria($criteria, $salesChannel);

        $criteria->addAssociation('mainCategories.category');
    }

    public function getMapping(Entity $product, ?SalesChannelEntity $salesChannel): SeoUrlMapping
    {
        if (!$product instanceof ProductEntity) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Expected ProductEntity');
        }

        $seoMapping = $this->decorated->getMapping($product, $salesChannel);
        $mainCategories = $product->getMainCategories();

        if (!$mainCategories) {
            return $seoMapping;
        }

        /** @var MainCategoryEntity|null $mainCategory */
        $mainCategory = $salesChannel ? $mainCategories->filterBySalesChannelId($salesChannel->getId())->first() : $mainCategories->first();

        if (!$mainCategory) {
            return $seoMapping;
        }

        $rootId = $this->detectRootId($mainCategory->getCategory(), $salesChannel);

        $breadcrumbs = $this->breadcrumbBuilder->build($mainCategory->getCategory(), $salesChannel, $rootId);

        $seoPathInfoContext = $seoMapping->getSeoPathInfoContext();
        $seoPathInfoContext['product']['seoBreadcrumb'] = $breadcrumbs;

        return new SeoUrlMapping(
            $seoMapping->getEntity(),
            $seoMapping->getInfoPathContext(),
            $seoPathInfoContext
        );
    }

    private function detectRootId(CategoryEntity $category, ?SalesChannelEntity $salesChannel): ?string
    {
        if (!$salesChannel) {
            return null;
        }
        $path = array_filter(explode('|', (string) $category->getPath()));

        $navigationId = $salesChannel->getNavigationCategoryId();
        if ($navigationId === $category->getId() || \in_array($navigationId, $path, true)) {
            return $navigationId;
        }

        $footerId = $salesChannel->getFooterCategoryId();
        if ($footerId === $category->getId() || \in_array($footerId, $path, true)) {
            return $footerId;
        }

        $serviceId = $salesChannel->getServiceCategoryId();
        if ($serviceId === $category->getId() || \in_array($serviceId, $path, true)) {
            return $serviceId;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Finally you will be able to use the breadcrumb within the template for your product seo urls:

```
{% if product.seoBreadcrumb is defined %}{% for part in product.seoBreadcrumb%}{{ part|lower  }}/{% endfor %}{% endif %}{{ product.translated.name }}/{{ product.productNumber }}
```